# Mockito.when().thenReturn() not working with @MockBean object using Kotlin and SpringTest

Tags: spring, kotlin, testing, mocking, mockito

I'm having some issues using Mockito.when().thenReturn() with the @MockBean i've got in my test.

Here's my test class:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Import(Config::class)
class ControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @MockBean
    private lateinit var kafkaPublisher: KafkaPublisher

    @Test
    fun valid payload(){
        Mockito.when(kafkaPublisher.sendEventListToKafka(anyList())).thenReturn(Unit)

        mockMvc.perform(
            post("/publish")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(getPayload()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk)
            .andExpect(content().string("Published 1 event(s) successfully"))
    }
}
```

where getPayload() returns the payload string that will be converted into the controller object using Jackson.

Here is the controller I am testing:

```
@Controller
class BumblebeeEventController {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var kafkaPublisher: KafkaPublisher

    @PostMapping("/publish")
    fun eventIntake(@RequestBody @Valid payload: EventList) : ResponseEntity<String>{

        kafkaPublisher.sendEventListToKafka(payload)

        return ResponseEntity("Published ${payload.events.size} event(s) successfully",HttpStatus.OK)
    }
}
```

I'm currently getting complaints from the Mockito.when.thenReturn usage:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.


    at com.ControllerTest.valid payload(ControllerTest.kt:39)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:221)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
```

Finally here is my KafkaPublisher:

```
open class KafkaPublisher @Autowired constructor(
        private val kafkaTemplate: KafkaTemplate<String, EventAvro>
)  {

    fun sendEventListToKafka(eventList: List<Event>){
        eventList.forEach {
            sendMessageToKafka(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), EventMapper.mapToEventAvro(it))
        }
    }

    fun sendMessageToKafka(uuid: String, message: EventAvro) {
        kafkaTemplate.send(kafkaTopic, uuid, message).get(3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        LOGGER.info("Successfully published into kafka topic ${kafkaTopic}, message: $message")
    }
```

I have 2 questions:

1. If I take out the Mockito.when.thenReturn the MockBean KafkaPublisher tries to actually publish the events to Kafka. I thought if it was mocked, it would just have a minimal implementation - e.g. return null, without any logic?
2. Why is Mockito not working with this KafkaPublisher class, thought it might be something to do with it being final so i made it open. Not sure what else it could be. Doesn't even like to take a real object instead of anyList() and any() doesn't work either?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify which annotation you are using. Your text and title say `@MockBean` but in the code you have `@Mock`. These annotations are doing different stuff, so it really matters with which it does not work.

Comment: Sorry it is mockbean, I was trying mock for testing most recently but that got nowhere either.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem 1: Mocking Unit methods**

You are trying to stub a method returning Unit.

```
Mockito.when(kafkaPublisher.sendEventListToKafka(anyList())).thenReturn(Unit)
```

This is incorrect. To stub void methods you need to use [doReturn()|doThrow()| doAnswer()|doNothing()|doCallRealMethod() family of methods](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#12)

Also note that for void methods, doing nothing is the default action.
Thus, the correct approach is to completely remove the discussed stubbing.

**Problem 2: Mocking final methods**

In Kotlin, all classes and methods are final by default.
You opened `KafkaPublisher` class, but did not open `sendEventListToKafka`  method.

Mockito, in its default config, cannot mock final methods. It can be configured to do with inline mock maker. This is why the original implementation of `sendEventListToKafka` is called.

However, Kotlin offers nice integration with spring via [kotlin-spring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#spring-support) plugin

> Thanks to meta-annotations support, classes annotated with @Configuration, @Controller, @RestController, @Service or @Repository are automatically opened since these annotations are meta-annotated with @Component.

If you annotate `KafkaPublisher` with `@Service` (instead of relying on @Configuration class to produce it) it will open both class amd its methods (My IDE even marks `open` keyword as redundant)

Comment: I also thought I didn't have to mock anything given the result doesn't matter and I just want to verify that the call is made once. However, the real Kafka method is actually being called and it doesn't seem to be mocked, I thought it would be a simple mock of return null

Comment: Any idea why that may be? It's question 1 in my original question.

Comment: Changed the mocking line to: Mockito.doNothing().`when`(kafkaPublisher).sendEventListToKafka(anyList()). I'm still having the same issue

Comment: See issue 2 above: you didn't open the method

Comment: I've added open to the method to the sendEventListToKafka and still no luck there, any idea why that's not working? Still exactly the same error.

Comment: Also I added @Component to the class which did mean by default it was open, but it caused all it's own problems and issues which means the application context can't load. So I still think the simplest way to solve this is to find out why I can't mock that one method.